# QGIS Reprojecting a layer CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a series of layers of lines (shapefiles) in My Project. The CRS of some are different and to merge them they all must have same CRS.

When I use Processing/Toolbox/Qgis_algorithims/Reproject_layer the reprojection only works if it is allowed to save to temporary file somewhere (it will not change the CRS when I reproject if I try to save and replace it in My Project directory); THEN

I must remove the original from the layer list and reproject the temp file (without changing the CRS) to get it into my project and name it appropriately.

Is this the only, or proper way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to reproject a layer is:

- for vector layers: `Save As ...`
- for raster layers: `Raster -> Projections -> Warp`

Both need a different filename and the CRS you want to reproject to. You can not reproject to the same file. If you want that, copy the source data to another folder, and replace the data within the project with the copy.